# C++ File I/O I cannot read the .dat file

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

struct WebSites
{
    string siteName;
    int rank;

    string getSiteName() { return siteName; }
    int getRank() { return rank; }
    WebSites(string const&, int);
    WebSites();
};

WebSites::WebSites(string const& siteName, int rank) {
    this->siteName = siteName;
    this->rank = rank;

}

WebSites::WebSites() {}

ostream& operator << (ostream& stream, WebSites const& data) {
    stream << data.rank << " " << data.siteName.size() << " " << data.siteName<< endl;
    return stream;

}

istream& operator >> (istream& stream, WebSites data) {
    stream >> data.siteName >> data.rank;
    return stream;

}


int main() {

    WebSites s1("www.google.co.uk", 1);

    //write to file

    ofstream writer("chou.dat", ios::out | ios::binary); //i'll add ios::app later
    if (!writer) {
        cout << " error opening file " << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        writer << s1.getSiteName() << " " << s1.getRank() << endl;
    }
    writer.close();

    //read file
    fstream writerR("chou.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::ate);
    WebSites read;
    while (writerR >> read) {

        cout << read.siteName << " rank: "<< read.rank << endl;
    }
    writerR.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me why this program won't read and display to console the file??? I mean it writes perfectly. I tried changing stuff, but nothing worked I checked similar code online and still nothing.

Comment: `fstream writerR` <-- if this is for reading, why not `ifstream` ?

Comment: Why would you call a reading stream `writeR`?  Why not call it `reader`?  Also always check that the file is open before you try to read from it

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but you pass ios::ate to the open which causes the file to seek to the end. There is nothing to be read from the end of the file. Also I would assume its better to use input file stream (ifstream) and you cannot read a whole struct like you are trying to do if you write each field separately. You specify binary mode yet you act like you are dumping text. As I see it, this code has not one but a couple of problems.

Comment: I mean the name doesn't really matter. I added the validator to check if it's open still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues:

1. Accouding to [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) specifying `ios::ate` would

   > seek to the end of stream immediately after open

   So there is simply nothing to read and your `while` loop would never be entered.
2. Another issue is here: `operator >> (istream& stream, WebSites data)`

   your operator is filling the copy with the data. To solve this second parameter should be a reference:

   `operator >> (istream& stream, WebSites& data)`

Comment: I understand I made the second parameter a referance, but it still doesn't work..

Comment: I figured out what you was saying and made the corrections for some reason It's still not working...